# jQuery: Updating global var and re-running function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that has another function nested that binds a click event to re-run that function with a different ajax URL:

```
function getInternal() {

      var callUrl = 'https://url.com'; // URL ON LOAD

      $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: callUrl, 

        success: function(data) {

          var obj = data;

          $( document ).ready(function(callUrl) {
            $( "a.dept" ).click(function() {
              var filterDept = $(this).attr('id');
              callUrl = 'https://url.com/' + filterDept; // URL TO UPDATE
              getInternal(callUrl); // RUN THIS FUNCTION AGAIN
            });
          });
```

Unfortunately the click event continues to return the same data. It doesn't look like callUrl is updating.

How do I update a global variable from within a function to re-run itself?

Comment: Each time you call `getInternal()`, you are re-setting the variable to the original.  Declare the variable outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your function sets your variable to a specific value: `var callUrl = 'https://url.com';` Thus, every single time you run this function, the variable will be set to `'https://url.com'`.

By moving your variable outside of the function it will become a global variable, and the portion of your code that updates callUrl will persist.

That being said, your code is all sorts of mixed up. You have `$( document ).ready()` within an AJAX callback, a `click` event that gets redefined within that with each call, nothing seems to be closed, and you've supplied a parameter for `getInternal();` despite the fact that it takes none.

Is something like this what you're after?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //On click of link, run AJAX call to changing URL (based on clicked link's ID)
    $( "a.dept" ).click(function() {
              var filterDept = $(this).attr('id');
              var callUrl = 'https://url.com/' + filterDept;
              getInternal(callUrl);
    });
  });

function getInternal(callUrl) {

      $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: callUrl, 

        success: function(data) {

          alert("Call made to " + callUrl);
          
          }
        
        });
  }
```

Comment: The reason I nested it in the ajax success is that the onclick needs to pick up the elements after the ajax call.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still not understanding. Declaring a click event with each successful AJAX callback doesn't seem practical in any case. Can you explain what your goal is and how it differs from my code above?

Comment: The click event doesn't work when it's outside the callback because the DOM hasn't loaded. I need .ready() to be after the Ajax call.

Comment: Can you please post the entirety of your code so we can understand what you're trying to achieve?